# Не нажимается кнопка "далее" в Инстаграмме на SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hq2O.jpg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a')
next.send_keys(Keys.Return)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```py
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a')
next.send_keys(Keys.Return)
```

Попробуйте

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow').click()
```

должно решить задачу.

Comment: Спасибо! За ответ смотрю и да получается

Answer (score 0):

```
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_65Bje')
```

если не сработает сделай вот так:

```
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name(' _65Bje')
```

еще есть вот такой вариант:

```
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('DdSX2')
```